# Laravel test breaks on attaching many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I have a test which should test the registration of a default User. The test function looks like the following:

```
   public function testCanRegister()
    {
        $this->json('POST', '/register', [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'johndoe@hotmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('1234')
        ])
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonFragment([
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'John Doe',
                'email' => 'johndoe@hotmail.com'
            ]);
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

> Expected status code 200 but received 500. Failed asserting that 200
>   is identical to 500.

The function it is testing is this:

```
   public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $user->email = $validatedData['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($validatedData['password']);
        $user->roles->attach(1); // give User role.

        if (!$user->save()) {
            return response()->json('Gebruiker kan niet worden geregistreerd', 500);
        }

        // Create session for the just registered User.
        Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => $request->json('password')
        ]);

        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
```

When I comment the line:

`$user->roles->attach(1);`

the test succeeds. Any ideas on how I can improve my test so it succeeds? The only thing that isn't working is attaching the role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like in [many to many relation doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> $user->roles()->attach($roleId);

so, when you attach, yo attach on relation, not a collection ...
please not that  $user->roles is collection of roles, while  $user->roles() is a relation ....

just update your statement to:

$user->roles()->attach(1);

Answer (score 1):

Try $user->roles()->attach(1); After saving user first.

like:

$user->save();

$user->roles()->attach(1);